# SVN: post-commit hook: adding text to comment field

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

When I do commit to the repo (from TSVN to VisualSVN server) I'd like to add to the comment a version of one of the files I'm committing.

For example the file version number (not svn revision) I'm going to commit is 4.0.56.896. I'd like this version number of this committing file appears in comment/message field. It will be useful because now if I'd like to read the file version number, for the svn revision given, I have to checkout the revision from the repo and them go to the file properties to read it.

The file version number is known. It can be obtained as a result of execution the exe file or obtained and stored and then pulled from the text file.

But how to add it to the comment in post-commit hook script?

EDIT:

Claryfying:

The problem I'd like to handle is:

I'd like to quickly know what is version of the .dll file committed at certain revision.

For example, as a result of commit the revision number is r1235. In this revision, let say I committed a file dll1.dll @ VERSION 4.0.56.896. Then I did a other commit to the repo. Let say after these commits I'm at revision r1490, and I need to check what was the VERSION of the dll1.dll file. The way I do it now I update WC to the revision and right click on the file and read from there.

So, I thought that it would be good to prepare a post-commit hook to put the information about VERSION of the dll1.dll file in the Comment/Message box, to avoid the "Update WC to revision" operation.

Answer (score 1):

First a straight forward answer..

In order to change the commit comment, you have to setup another `pre-revprop-change` hook to allow for changes of revision properties. Allowing pellmell changes to revision properties can be a dangerous practice because users can change who committed a change and when. This is why changing revision properties isn't allowed out of the box.

So, first create a `pre-revprop-change` hook. An example script is given as `pre-revprop-change.tmpl` in the `hooks` directory of the Subversion repository directory. It only allows changing the `svn:log` revision property, but doesn't verify if it's the same user.

Once you create such a hook, adding a post-commit hook that changes the commit comment is fairly straight forward. The `$REVISION` and `$REPO` are passed to the `post-commit` hook, all you have to do is get the commit message via `svn pg --revprop svn:log -r $REV $REPO` and then modify it, and set the commit message via `svn ps svn:log --revprop -r "$commit_msg" $REV`.

Getting back to your ORIGINAL question:

> When I do commit to the repo (from TSVN to VisualSVN server) I'd like to add to the comment a version of one of the files I'm committing.

What is that *version*? If it's the Subversion revision, I wouldn't bother. If there is some version.txt file, you could pull it from there. If each file has a different *version*, then you're simply going to add confusion if you commit more than one file and each file has a different version.

What is the issue you're having, and is this the best way to solve that problem? Explain this, and I can probably give you a much better answer than attempting to manipulate a commit comment on the fly.

---

### A Way Better Answer

What you want is a way to find what you released to the customer. The customer has version 4.0.56.896 and you want to be able to find that particular revision.

That's what tagging is for. When you release your software to the customer, you should tag it. Heck, you could even tag it as 4.0.56.896. It's way faster to find the tag than to search the log and then try to figure out whether or not you checked it out. You don't have to worry about changing commit comments either.

What it really sounds like is that you need a bit better control over your build and release process. Is every release something the customer might have? Do you do any testing? Is there a release schedule, or are you chasing bugs and constantly putting out fires?

This is what change control is all about. I suggest you look at [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) to help your build process. Jenkins will automatically build and test your code with each change (or on a schedule if you prefer). You can trace the history of your project, and even track the status of builds  For example, we change the build description when the build is moved from development testing to QA testing to UAT testing. It helps us track what's going on. We even do our tagging through Jenkins.

Jenkins can also hold your build products, so you don't check them into Subversion. (Please tell me you don't check in your built binaries into Subversion. That's another bad practice.). You can also integrate [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org) into your build process. (NuGet helps you package reusable DLLs or whatever .NET produces, so you can use them in other projects).

Comment: David - your solution **will work**, but it's bad in common sense, because it will not fix broken workflow. OP doesn't store any VCS-metadata in (not-text) own product and want to detect relation "File Version"-"Revision" in repository in reverse order (on demand on customer, AFAICS)

Comment: I now see the OP changed the question after I gave my answer and gave more details too. I know my solution was far from ..uh.. optimal. That's why I told the OP _"is this the best way to solve the problem? Explain this, and I can give you a better answer"_

Comment: Tagging is only part of (good full) solution, **if** some amount of releases can be used in parallel by customers and for bug-report you *must* to know, which version of app at customer-side produced troubles

Comment: @user1146081 Would Jenkins or NuGet help your situation? You shouldn't store compiled code in Subversion. It isn't only a bad CM practice, but greatly bloats the repo. You'll soon find that your repo is +20Gb in size and is composed of 99% compiled code you no longer care about. Store releases in a release repo. We store released compiled code in Jenkins builds.

Comment: DavidW: Mainly I use repos to store LabVIEW modules which are compiled. I cannot detach source code from the compiled version. I have no way out of this. I'm investigating Jenkins anyway.

Comment: But going back to the main question: how I can attach additional string to the message during commit?

Comment: I answered that, but then told you it is not a good idea. Use tags. It's much easier finding `4.0.56.896` as a tag rather than rummaging through commit comments looking for the string. It involves less work and no mucking around with hooks and possibly munging a commit comment and destroying it.

Comment: @user1146081 - If you're using LabView with .NET, look at [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org) for storing LabView's compiled modules.

Answer (score 0):

While David's answer *is technically correct*...

- In you store File Version as special subversion-property of file, you can get it directly from URL, without checkout, read carefully `svn help pg`

Just sample for existing in repository file (I haven't another properties and too lazy to create sample-repo)

```
>svn pg svn:keywords "^/trunk/Scartel-Yota.ini"
Date Revision Author Id
```

- Even existing possibility to add additional layer into workflow is not excuse for DBW ("Damned Broken Workflow"): why, if you have to get information from file about revision of this file in repository, you just don't store this data instead of useless crap in File Version or another (special?) field. Most projects (which I can monitor) with VCS in developent use the last octet in "File Version" field for storing (Subversion) revision in it

**Sample 1**

```
>wmic datafile where Name="FlylinkDC.exe" get Version
Version

7, 7, 503, 17574
```

and `17574` *is revision of compilation* of this file

**Sample 2**

```
>wmic datafile where Name="TortoiseProc.exe" get Version
Version
1.8.8.25755
```

I *suppose* `25755` is revision,  but this data (fully) added into about screen in order to easy identify used version of application

> TortoiseSVN 1.8.8, Build 25755 - 32 Bit , 2014/08/10 14:44:06